# Pointer initialisation to a constant value - segmention fault

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question and I am little confused about the output I am getting. Could someone please help me out with this.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *i = 5;
  char *c = i[1];
  printf("%c", *c);
}
```

`

Will it compile properly without errors. If it compiles, will it give a segmentation fault during runtime. If yes, because of which line. According to me the first 2 lines of the main() are ok. The printf statement gives a segmentation fault but I am not able to justify it. here int *i is initialized to a constant. So I can point 'i' to some other location but cannot change *i. I am assigning the second byte of 'i' to char *c but here I am not changing *i. Then why printing *c gives segmentation fault. This is my view. Looking for a better explanation.

Comment: @moooeeeep Its not homework :) its an interview question. I knew there would be segmentation fault but I could not give a satisfactory explanation for this.

Answer (score 2):

By doing `int *i = 5;` you get a pointer points to an invalid memory address. That's fine as long as you don't do pointer arithmetics on it, and don't dereference it.

By doing `char *c = i[1];`, you do perform pointer arithmetics on that pointer (where the object pointed to is not an array) and are even dereferencing it. Both means you're invoking undefined behavior. At the same time you declare an initialize another pointer that points to an invalid memory address.

By doing `printf("%c", *c);`, you again dereference an invalid pointer address, which is again invoking undefined behavior. That is, anything can happen, including a segmentation fault.

Note that you only observe a segmentation fault because you are running on an operating system that is aware of such forms of malicious code and rejects its further execution. Undefined behavior is not guaranteed to fail. And the thing is, the compiler is not required to inform you about such issues with your code.

Answer (score 1):

`int *i = 5;` creates a pointer that points to the **address** 5, not to the **address of the number** 5. You should do:

```
int a = 5;
int *i = &a;
```

Also, since `i` is a pointer to an `int`, the behavior is undefined for the following:

```
char *c = i[1];
//        ^ returns an int, not a char pointer
```

Comment: but the code compiles without errors for the first 2 lines in main(). I mean excluding the printf statement.

Comment: @Kahaly the compiler is not required to even warn you about such errors.

Comment: Also note the undefined behavior due to accessing an `int`-sized value past the end of a not-an-array being used as an array...

Comment: @BinyaminSharet "int *i = 5; creates a pointer that points to the address 5, not to the address of the number 5." I have doubt in this. when we write `char *p = "Hello";` Here p actually points to the starting address of the string. Likewise, `int *i = 5` I should point to the starting address of the number 5.

Comment: @Kahaly `5` is not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can **NOT** initialize pointer from a static value. Your code initializes `i` to point to memory address `5`, which is certainly not your applications memory. To do what you want, you need this:

```
int x = 5;
int* i = &x;
```

The `&` is the address of operator that gets the address of the int `x`, which holds the value `5`. As for your second line, that is completely invalid. A pointer to an `int` like that will not support the `[]` operator, even if it is an array. You either want:

- The value of `i`: `*i`
- The first byte of `i`: Don't try unless you have a good reason

Then, you assign that value to a pointer, which is also invalid. You'll need to use `&` again.

Comment: I know the correct way of doing it. But the code snippet was asked in an interview and I was not sure of the explanation to this particular code snippet. The code compiles without errors for the first 2 lines in main(). I mean excluding the printf statement. We can initialize pointer to a constant. The following statement is perfectly fine. `char *ptr = "Hello";` In the case `int *i = 5;` should also be fine i guess.

Comment: @Kahaly: From a compiler standpoint? Yes. From the kernels standpoint? No. The compiler doesn't know what your code will be allowed to do on it's target system. You could be writing a boot loader that can do anything. But the kernel is in control while you run the code and refuses to let you access address 5, which your process doesn't own. As for `const char* str = "Hi"`, that points `str` to a read only section of the executable where literal strings are stored.

Comment: @Kahaly: "Undefined behavior" means the compiler doesn't have to warn you that you're doing something wrong.  The behavior of `int *i = 5;` by itself isn't undefined, but the behavior of `char *c = i[1];` and `printf ("%c", *c);` most certainly are because `i` and `c` contain invalid pointer values.

Comment: @JohnBode `int *i = 5;` Does it point to the starting address of number 5 or to the address location 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

```
int *i = 5;
```

You're initializing the pointer `i` with the *address* 5.  There are at least a couple of problems with this.  First of all, most modern architectures (such as x86) insist that multibyte types such as `int` be aligned so that they start on even-numbered addresses.  Secondly, 5 is an awfully low address value, and depending on the platform may not be available to your program (making it an *invalid* address).

```
char *c = i[1];
```

Now you're declaring a pointer to `char` and initializing it with the value of the *integer* stored at the next integer address after `i` (either 7 or 9 or some other address, which is already problematic as explained above; this by itself could cause a segmentation fault).  Beyond typing issues (the type of the expression `i[1]` is `int`, not `char *`), it's almost guaranteed that the contents of `i[1]` are a random bit string that doesn't correspond to a valid memory address.

And this is why you get the segmentation fault in the `printf` statement; `*c` is attempting to dereference an invalid pointer.

So no, the first two lines of `main` are *most definitely not* okay.

Comment: `int *i = 5;` Does it point to the starting address of number 5 or to the address location 5. I thought it points to the address of number 5 since `char *ptr = "Hello";` points to the starting address of the string "Hello". Does it work differently for integer pointers? All pointers whether integer or character at the end of the day is an integer value storing an address location.

Comment: String literals are different from numeric literals.  String literals are stored as arrays of `char` in such a way that they're allocated when the program starts up and held until the program exits.  Numeric literals such as `5`, OTOH, are not assigned any storage, and as such don't have an address (they are not lvalues).  When you write `int *i = 5`, you're assigning the literal value `5` to `i`.